# Embedding Youtube clip in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube

I have a you tube clip in my rails app. Profiles include video introductions.

I have a profile model with a youtube_url attribute.

I have a profile_helper with the following:

```
module ProfilesHelper

  def embed(youtube_url)
     youtube_id = youtube_url.split("=").last
     content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{youtube_id}")
   end
end


<div class="embed-container"> 
  <%= embed(profile.youtube_url) %>  
</div>
```

However, I get an error when I try to test this that identifies a problem with the embed line above:

```
undefined local variable or method `profile' for #<#<Class:0x00000103f434f0>:0x00000107f84f00>
```

My profiles controller has:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  #decorates_assigned :profile
  before_action :authenticate_user! 
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.json
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show


  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.json
  def create

    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    @profile.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def profile_params
      params[:profile].permit(
      :title, :languages, :overview, :research_interests, :occupation, :about_me, 
      :interested_in, :aspirations, :advice, :average_day, :like_to, :fyi_fact, :timezone, :image, :university_id,
      :link_to_external_profile, :youtube_url
      )
    end
end
```

Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Thank you

Comment: In `<%= embed(profile.youtube_url) %>` `profile` was not found. Is the associate controller method for this view file returning the `profile` variable correctly? could you please give a code snippet of the controller method for this view file?

Comment: Hi - amended above. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the view code to refer to `@profile` instead of `profile` as follows:

```
<div class="embed-container"> 
  <%= embed(@profile.youtube_url) %>  
</div>
```

The `@profile` instance variable is being correctly set in the `set_profile` profile method.

Comment: Thanks Prakash. That solved that error. Now I get this error: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass - referring to the profiles helper.

Comment: Please add a different question for the different error.